# PL/SQL Storing row into a variable and using them in for loop

Tags: database, oracle, loops, plsql, cursor

I am writing a script and got an error while saving row values into variable 
I am trying to update a table for which I need to fetch from other corresponding tables

```
DECLARE
cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
dept_row department%rowtype;
employee_row employee%rowtype;
status number :=0;
BEGIN

FOR employee_details IN (select * from employee_details_table)
LOOP
select * into dept_row from department dept where employee_details.dept_id = dept.dept_id;
select * into employee_row from employee emp where emp.dept_id = empoyee_details.dept_id;

IF employee_details.valid <> employee_row.valid THEN
 // call SP which uses values from both dept_row & employee_row
END IF;
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

When I run the above SQL I am getting error.
ORA-01722
ORA-06512

I am unable to figure out what's wrong with above code.
Please help

Thanks

Comment: You are using the `collection` incorrectly. Also, better to avoid the loop using for and use bulk collect and forall statement to minimise the overhead of context switch between sql and plsql engines. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `collection` incorrectly. Also, better to avoid the `loop` using `for` and use `bulk collect` and `forall statement` to minimise the overhead of `context switch` between `sql and plsql engines`.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_bulk_collect_test_tab IS TABLE OF employee_table%ROWTYPE;

  l_tab t_bulk_collect_test_tab;

  CURSOR c_data IS
    SELECT *
    FROM employee_table;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_data;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_data
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab LIMIT 10000;
    EXIT WHEN l_tab.count = 0;

.......

End;
```

For more examples on collections, bulk collect and forall statements, please refer the examples here http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/bulk-binds-and-record-processing-9i.php

Remember, better to avoid `loops`. `Row by row` is `slow by slow`.